# Dynamic RMarkdown Title from R Code Chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

Consider the following .Rmd file:

````
---
author: "Test"
date: "September 27, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
days <- 60
title <- paste0(days, " Days")
```
````

The output of `title` above, namely `"60 Days"`, without quotes is the title I would like to have outputted into the .html file (which would originally be under `title:` in the above if it were hard-coded).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary R code anywhere you want in an Rmarkdown document (including the title) by surrounding the block with `` ` `` ticks and putting an `r` in front of the code:

So this (note the `;` between lines of code):

```
---
author: "Test"
date: "September 27, 2018"
output: html_document
title: '`r days <- 60; paste0(days, " Days")`'
---
```

Knits as this:

[image]

---

As [@camille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5325862/camille) pointed out, you can also include yaml blocks later in the file by surrounding them with the same `---` as in the initial header. This lets you make use of variables defined later in the code:

You can also include R chunks inline in markdown and use R expressions to control the display of markdown:

````
---
author: "Test"
date: "September 27, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
debug <- 2
num1 <- 3
```

`r if(debug > 3){"## Debug is > 3"}`
`r if(debug < 3){"## Debug is < 3"}`

The value of num1 is `r num1`

---
title: '`r paste0('Title: the value of debug is ', debug)`'
---
````

Renders as this:

[image]

Comment: I'd add to that that you can insert a yaml block later in the file. I often do this when I need the title to take part of its name from a parameter that's evaluated later on. Surround the `title: params$whatever` in `---` like any other yaml front-matter